# Peskin and Schroder Equation 4.37 invalid

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, wick-theorem

In chapter 4 of Peskin & Schroeder,
\begin{align}
T\{\phi(x)\phi(y)\} &= N\{ \phi(x)\phi(y)+ \text{Contraction}({\phi(x),\phi(y)}) \}, \tag{4.37}\\
& = N\{ \phi(x)\phi(y)\}+ N\{\text{Contraction}({\phi(x),\phi(y)}) \}. \tag{linearity of $N$}
\end{align}

If for instance $x_0>y_0$, using the definition of $T$ and Contraction we have that
$$\phi(x)\phi(y)=N\{ \phi(x)\phi(y)\}+ N\{ [\phi^+(x),\phi^-(y) ] \}.$$

This makes no sense, as

\begin{align}
N\{ [\phi^+(x),\phi^-(y) ] \} &= N\{ \phi^+(x)\phi^-(y) -\phi^-(y)\phi^+(x)  \}, \\
&=\phi^+(x)\phi^-(y)-\phi^+(x)\phi^-(y), \\
&=0.
\end{align}
where it should really of course not be affected by the normal ordering.

Clearly the problem is it seems like the Contraction in (4.37) should not be normal ordered. Why is it? I know this has been asked before but the answers are not direct. Please answer the question directly.

Comment: What is the problem with the existing answers ?

Comment: Besides them all being garbage? They all state that the problem is due to having the identity operator not be defined in P&S. How is this relevant at all? Can someone give an answer that isn't insanely formal, and that actually makes sense? It seems like it would only be a few lines..

Comment: In general telling people something is garbage is not telling them anything that lets them find out what your issue is, so maybe eave that kind of remark out.  A link to an example Q&A would be more useful.  Don't expect other people to search for Q&A if you want help - you have to make it easy for them to know what you want.  Finally a title change to reflect what you actually want might also help, e.g. "Why is this contraction normally ordered ?".

Comment: Yeah sorry that was immature of me. I will do that next time

Comment: Asked before where? Link?

Comment: Related: [What is the calculation rule of the normal ordering operator?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/395243/168783)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that the Wick contraction is defined as
\begin{equation}
\text{Contr}(\phi(x)\phi(y))\equiv \langle 0 |T\{\phi(x) \phi(y)\}|0\rangle.
\end{equation}

From this definition, we see that the Wick contraction is a number, not an operator. So the notation $[\phi^-(x),\phi^+(y)]$ when $x_0>y_0$ is to be understood as being a number. In fact, a more concrete notation would be
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
\langle 0 |[\phi^-(x),\phi^+(y)]| 0 \rangle \,\,\,\text{if}\,\,\, x_0>y_0, \\
\langle 0 |[\phi^-(y),\phi^+(x)]| 0 \rangle \,\,\,\text{if}\,\,\, x_0 < y_0. 
\end{matrix}
\right.
\end{equation}
This shortcut in the notation is common in quantum mechanics. For example, the Heisenberg uncertainty principle is written as $[x,p]=i\hbar$, but in truth it is $[x,p]=i\hbar \times \text{Id}$, where $\text{Id}$ is the identity operator. But here we see that the number corresponding to the commutator $[\phi^-(x),\phi^+(y)]$ will go out of the expectation value, leaving just $\langle 0 | \text{Id} | 0 \rangle =1$ in factor of it.